# Why can't I log into Google Play at https://play.google.com/apps/publish/ to publish an Android app?

Tags: android, google-play

It has been 1 year since I've used this account to publish an Android app built with React Native. The previous app was disabled during that time. I wanted to start and configure a new app page to prepare for uploading the APK and inviting users to test the new app. When trying to log into the Google Play console a 403 status error page is displayed without any explanation. How do I resolve this issue?

[image: google play publishing console can't log in error]

Comment: Why would someone downvote this? It is a legitimate question!

Comment: you might feel your question is legitimate, but stack overflow requires a [Minimal, Reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and we can't help you with customer service related issues, [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions/255746#255746)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue today when the link to the Console worked last night and OP's answer wasn't the case with my problem.

Head to https://play.google.com/console/ and log-in from there. In my case, my shortcut I had saved must've been an old URL being deprecated by Google in their process of rolling in the new Console fully (I'm guessing).

Answer (score 0):

The owner of the parent account, logged in and had to pay $2. Although, the child account, mine, was associated with the parent account before neither the previous app existed nor my account associated with the organization. The owner needed to add my account as a user on the permissions page and I now have access.